# Why does it delete data elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, trie

I tried to implement trie data structure in JS following certain tutorial. http://jsbin.com/ilamic/3/edit

It works, but there's a problem:

it only works when i invoke simultaneously insert_key() and start_with_prefix() - i get nothing if i comment out insert_key() and invoke only start_with_prefix() ! :(  Data just disappear! How do i make it stay there, once inserted?

P.S.: That tutorial was Python tutorial - i adapted it into JS code. Maybe, i missed something(

Comment: @Chase  Should i repost everything here from jsbin??

Comment: My apologies, I thought that was a link to the python code when reading through the post and didn't look at it. =)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you missed a very simple thing, every time the code is executed the variable ***tr*** is reinitialized, so if you try to execute **start_with_prefix()** without populating it with **insert_key()** it will be empty. you need to save the state of your variable to reuse it later.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/iyemax/2/edit) I've cloned your original example and added some logic. Hope this help.